# Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.04 can't show pdf thumbnail

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, pdf, thumbnails

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on two machines. One can show pdf thumbnail, another can't. I tried to install and reinstall evince, but still, it is not shown.
Anyone knows what am I missing?

Here is an example. Only pdf (maybe ps also) is missing thumbnails.
[image].

And here is another machine that shows pdf thumbnails (including eps file).

[image]

Comment: I assume you are using `evince`. Just delete the `~/.cache/thumbnails` folder and restart the system. The thumbnails will appear of PDFs

Comment: It didn't work. I tried this many times. Other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact solution for me.
First, the task to make pdf thumbnails are performed by evince-thumbnailer. Hence I check my evince-thumbnailer script here: `/usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer`. I saw the third line is commented:

```
Thumbnailer Entry]                                                         
TryExec=evince-thumbnailer                                                  
#Exec=evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o                                         
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application    /x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostsc    ript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;appl    ication/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi    ;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;application/x-ext-    djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;ap    plication/x-cb7;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ex    t-cb7;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
```

I checked in another machine and it is not commented out. So, the solution is jut uncomment the third line:

```
Exec=evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
```

And whoaa, the pdf files now show the thumbnails!

Maybe in the last, this script makes my computer hung, so I commented out that line.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. It works too on Linux Lite 4.8 based in Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks my friend To edit I do "nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer" (without "")